# Hindi font on Google Chrome looks better on Android than on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, android

I have noticed that webpages in Hindi look terrible on Windows as compared to my tablet. I am using Google Chrome on both. I have tried Windows 7 (laptop) and Windows 8 (desktop), and Nexus 10 tablet.

This is the webpage I am trying to view (although this applies to other Hindi pages too) : http://www.bbc.co.uk/hindi/india/2013/09/130913_hello_laddakh_diary_sk.shtml

This is how it looks on Windows and Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEkj.jpg

I really like the way it looks on Android. How can I get it to look the same on Windows as well? Is it using a different font? How can I get the same font on Windows?